# Is it okay to repeat the same column in an UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

I have an update statement where each portion is separately generated. The ideal situation is to produce this:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET column1 = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
       ...
 WHERE ...
```

However, I have to make do with this:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET column1 = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END,
       column1 = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END
       ...
 WHERE ...
```

I tried running it and it works.

I would like to know whether there is any gotchas or anything if I were do stick with that.

UPDATE: The WHEN ... THEN actually contains column related conditions. e.g WHEN column2 = ... THEN ...

e.g.

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET column1 = CASE 
        WHEN column2 = 'a' THEN 'foo' 
        WHEN column2 = 'b' THEN 'bar' 
        ELSE null 
      END, 
      column1 = CASE 
        WHEN column2 = 'c' THEN 'foobar' 
        WHEN column2 = 'd' THEN 'barbar' 
        ELSE null 
      END 
WHERE key = ...
```

Comment: If your CASE WHEN statements are mutually exclusive, it should work. But if they can be true for 2 different lines, behavior is undefined.

Comment: @P.Salmon No. It requires me to redo the code to generate the correct output.

Comment: @ADyson The WHEN ... THEN consists of conditions related to values of certain columns of the row to be updated.

Comment: I know that. But what's your point? You're still trying to give the field in `column1` of each row two different values at the same time. I've never tried to do anything as weird as this so I don't know what exactly would happen, but I'd guess that maybe the value generated by the first CASE statement is set on the field, and then the second CASE statement is evaluated and that overwrites the value in the field with the result of that statement instead. Depending on what the actual logic is in the CASE statements, you might get away with it, but it's not a good idea in general.

Comment: @ADyson UPDATE mytable SET column1 = CASE WHEN column2 = 'a' THEN 'foo' WHEN column2 = 'b' THEN 'bar' ELSE null END, column1 = CASE WHEN column2 = 'c' THEN 'foobar' WHEN column2 = 'd' THEN 'barbar' ELSE null END WHERE key = ...

Comment: Be aware that if it works, it'll be relying on mysql specific behaviour, and even [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) all I can find is the vague "Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right" and confirmation it doesn't follow the standards.

Comment: from a quick test I'd suggest that a likely outcome is that if column2 contains "foo" or "bar" then the final value that ends up in column1 will be NULL (i.e. the NULL generated by the second CASE statement). But whether that's chance or actually defined behaviour in such a scenario I don't know. It's my repeatable observation, that's all. Here's a working demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foYWchffxkFkxtQuuRsDgC/1 So I'm not sure how you claim it "works" - have you tested all scenarios properly?

Comment: Here's a slight tweak with the NULL outputs replaced by differing values, so you can see exactly what the behaviour is and which clause is generating the final value: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foYWchffxkFkxtQuuRsDgC/2 . You really have to modify your code, you can't stick with this unreliable version.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks.  I have modified it to make it inline.

Comment: @Yaskov No problem. Now it's certain I have added as a full answer - if you would care to upvote and/or mark it as accepted that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to give the field in column1 of each row two different values at the same time. This really doesn't make any logical sense and is likely to lead to unexpected or undesirable behaviour. It's unclear what

From a quick test I'd suggest that a likely outcome is that if `column2` contains `"foo"` or `"bar"` then the final value that ends up in `column1` will be `NULL` (i.e. the `NULL` generated by the second CASE statement). It seems that SQL will evaluate the first CASE statement, and then the second CASE statement. Therefore the value returned by the second statement overwrites the value in the field with the result of that statement instead of the first one. Effectively this means the first CASE statement is useless.

Here's a working demo of that test: https://db-fiddle.com/f/foYWchffxkFkxtQuuRsDgC/1

And here's a slight tweak with the NULL outputs replaced by differing values, so you can see exactly what the behaviour is and which clause is generating the final value: https://db-fiddle.com/f/foYWchffxkFkxtQuuRsDgC/2 .

But whether that's chance or actually defined/documented behaviour in such a scenario I don't know for sure. It's my repeatable observation, that's all.

Either way, you really have to modify your code, you can't stick with this unreliable version.

It seems you already know the answer, but for clarity here is a reliable version which only attempts to set the column  value once:

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET column1 = CASE 
        WHEN column2 = 'a' THEN 'foo' 
        WHEN column2 = 'b' THEN 'bar' 
        WHEN column2 = 'c' THEN 'foobar' 
        WHEN column2 = 'd' THEN 'barbar' 
        ELSE null 
      END 
WHERE key = ...
```